# ssh-copy-id different port

Tags: ssh, command-line, file-copy, port-forwarding

i am trying execute ssh-copy-id in one port different than 22 (default). I researched and found the command below

`$ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub "user@192.168.0.1 -p 22001"`

but, when execute the command, i got this error:

`/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.1 -p 22001 port 22: Connection refuse`

It seems that command dont understand the port.

Comment: quote (") are not needed. what you write is : I need to copy key to a host name "user@192.168.0.1 p 22001" with same user ans standard port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ ssh-copy-id
Usage: /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id [-h|-?|-n] [-i [identity_file]] [-p port] [[-o <ssh -o options>] ...] [user@]hostname
```

So in your case simply use:

```
$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -p 22001 user@192.168.0.1
```

Because of your usage of quotes, the `-p 22001` part became part of the hostname which explains the error you got.